# Dart/Flutter Map has empty strange empty key, leading to a value

Tags: string, flutter, dictionary, dart, key

This is incredibly bizzarre.

I have a very complex class that should have probably used objects instead of madly nested arrays.  Anyway when it comes time to save everything I'm ending up with a strange appendix to my primary data structure loanItemDetails.  I've printed it to logs and it has this

`loanItemDetails = {: {exists: true}, roundCakeTin: {charges: true, rent: 5, exists: true}...}`

breaking that down:

`keys = (, roundCakeTin`

`values = ({exists: true}, {charges: true, rent: 5, exists: true}`

It's unwanted.  How do I look for a null key?  Is that what it is?  Or is an empty String serving as the key?  Or...?
I've begun looking at anywhere where I assign `"exists": true`, but it's torturous, I'd love some improved intuition.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove null values from a dictionary, you can use this:

```
void main() {
  final map = {'text': null, 'body': 5, null: 'crap', 'number': 'ten'};

  map.removeWhere((key, value) => key == null || value == null);

  print(map); // {body: 5, number: ten}
}
```

I don't see your original data structure in your question. If you expand on that I can improve this answer.